# Passing object property

Tags: javascript, css, parameters, frameworks, parameter-passing

Working on my little JS framework. Trying to create a toggle method. This is the code:

```
function $elect(id) {
    if (!(this instanceof $elect)) {
        return new $elect(id);
    }
    this.elm = document.getElementById(id);
}

$elect.prototype = {
    toggle:     function (prop, val1, val2) {
                    if (this.elm.style.prop != val2) {
                        this.elm.style.prop = val2;
                    } else {
                        this.elm.style.prop = val1;
                    }
                }
}

window.$elect = $elect;
```

And using `$elect(id).toggle('background', 'red', 'blue')` to call it. But of course this won't work. I'm trying to find a way to hmm... how do I say it? I want to pass `'background'` to `this.elm.style.prop` so I can also use the other css properties. How do I replace `prop` in `this.elm.style.prop` with the parameter I'm passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reference a key in an object with

```
object[key]
```

where key is a string.

So in your case, it'd be

```
this.elm.style[prop]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZJWdA/
Here's an example.

Comment: Sweet. Btw, by saying 'a key', do you mean its properties? Totally new to this.

Comment: They're interchangeable terms from my experience.